# Angular bootstrap typeahead with asynchronous load is one character behind

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I have implemented the following typeahead code in a directive.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text"
           ng-model="company"
           uib-typeahead="company as company.name for company in companyByName($viewValue)"
           typeahead-loading="loadingCompanies"
           typeahead-no-results="noCompanyResults"
           class="form-control">
    <i ng-show="loadingCompanies" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
    <div ng-show="noCompanyResults">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
  scope.companyByName = function() {
    var companyName = scope.company.name ? scope.company.name : scope.company;
    var searchTerms = {name: companyName, startRow: 0, endRow: 20};

    return $http.post("backend/get/companies.php", searchTerms).then((result) => {
      $log.info("Companies", result.data.results);
      return result.data.results;
    });
  };
```

The PHP code `backend/get/companies.php` accepts a search string and returns an array of objects with `id` and `name` attributes with names that contain that search string.

Here is the behavior that I am experiencing:

When I type a single character "f" into the typeahead field, the value of `companyName` passed to the backend script is "" (empty string). `backend/get/companies.php` returns all results.

When I type a second character "fo" in the the typeahead field, the value of `companyName` passed to the backend script is "f".  `backend/get/companies.php` returns results that match "f".

Typing a third character "foo" returns results that match "fo", etc.

I have modeled my code after the [official examples](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). What is going on? My feeling is that somehow the `companyByName()` function is being called by an event that fires before the character is entered into the input. Any thoughts?

Comment: use $viewValue for search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that ng-model is lagging behind view values. When `companyByName` is called ng-model is not updated to latest value from input field. To get latest value from input you should use argument that is passed into `companyByName` function:

```
scope.companyByName = function(viewValue) {
  var searchTerms = {name: viewValue, startRow: 0, endRow: 20};

  return $http.post("backend/get/companies.php", searchTerms).then((result) => {
    $log.info("Companies", result.data.results);
    return result.data.results;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Typeahead must be faster than the page digest and therefore using scope instead of value its just not quite there.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tKNs7kFDCwLlPRJJP53I?p=preview) is a plunker showing both versions. Essentially you need the first version as below

```
 scope.companyByName = function(val) {
    var companyName = val;
    var searchTerms = {name: companyName, startRow: 0, endRow: 20};

    return $http.post("backend/get/companies.php", searchTerms).then((result) => {
      $log.info("Companies", result.data.results);
      return result.data.results;
    });
  };
```